# Не работает logout в django

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

В проекте есть `rest_framework` и метод `api/logout`:

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout
from rest_framework.views import APIView

class LogoutView(APIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request):
        logout(request)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Но после того, как фронтенд дергает logout, другие авторизованные методы api остаются доступными! 
Т.е. пользователя почему-то в браузере не разлогинивает...

Comment: 1. убедитесь, что logout действительно вызывается (дебаг, отладка). 2. проверьте, доступны ли методы api в режиме инкогнито

Comment: у меня есть unit-тесты для этого и они проходят. более того - подключен swagger и в нем login/logout (через методы api) работает как надо. 
т. е. видимо что-то не так с фронтом, и это очень странно)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Столкнулся с этим вопросом.

Изучив исходники `django-rest-auth`, обнаружил следующее: метод `logout`, описанный в `django-rest-auth`, сначала удаляет токен пользователя, а затем вызывает метод `logout` самого `django`. В вашем коде сразу вызывается метод `logout django`, так что токен остаётся валидным.

**Решение** вытекает из проблемы: вызовите `logout` из `rest-auth`.